# Most frequent text in column dynamically

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Still working on the dashboard, you guys save me so much time - I've also been learning so much!

I have a formula which works for only the entries already in there, but it doesn't work if i try to extend from A2:A1000 (Simple INDEX, MODE, MATCH)


**MY GOAL:**

- Show the most frequent location from column A
- Keep counting new data entries in column A indefinitely (dynamic)
- If two locations have the same frequency (and are both the most frequent), print one at random or print the highest one in the column (doesn't matter as long as it works)

**CURRENT FORMULA**

```
=INDEX(A2:A7,MODE(MATCH(A2:A7,A2:A7,0)))
```

**DATA:**

```
       A
1   LOCATION
2   dallas
3   dallas
4   miami
5   LA
6   LA
7   atlanta
8
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
dallas
```

If I extend the scope beyond A7, the output is **"#N/A"**

Thanks.

Comment: "I have a formula which works" - what is it?

Comment: _"Show the most frequent location from column A"_ so if there is a tie... ?

Comment: My formula is this: =INDEX(A2:A7,MODE(MATCH(A2:A7,A2:A7,0)))

If I try to extend the scope beyond A7, I get an error - That's my issue. I need it to be dynamic with my data input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out for anyone who is interested.

**New formula** (Press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER)

```
=INDEX(A2:A995,MODE(IF((A2:A995<>"")*ISNA(MATCH(A2:A995,$A$1:$A1,0)),MATCH(A2:A995,A2:A995,0))))
```